# XSL select text in parent node with all children except one specific child node

Tags: xml, xslt, select

I have a problem with XML and XSL,
This is a portion of my XML document:

```
<node1>
    <node2>
        <node3>text inside node3 I don't want select</node3>
        text inside node2 that I want select
        <node4> text in node4 I want select</node4>
    </node2>
</node1>
```

node2 has some text inside and 2 children (node3 and node4), I need to select the text contained in node2 with the text in child node4 EXCEPT the one 
in node3.
I also say that the structure of the node2 is not always the same,sometime it has some text only, or might have some text with node3 and/or node4.
Also the order of the elements inside node2 may not always be the same but the result's order should be the same as that in the XML's order.

Thanks for the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the `node2` context, you could get all descendant text nodes except those that are inside a `node3` using

```
.//text()[not(parent::node3)]
```

or more generally, if `node3` might have child elements

```
<node2>
   keep this
   <node3>drop this <node7>drop this too</node7></node3>
   <node4>keep this</node4>
</node2>
```

then use `ancestor:: instead of`parent::`

```
.//text()[not(ancestor::node3)]
```

Comment: I have try to test you first solution but it seems doesn't work properly. Like in my example, it selects the text inside the node2 but doesn't select the text inside node4.

Comment: I have also test the second solution, but it shows the same problem.

Comment: @GiulioBambini It depends what you mean by "doesn't select" - remember that this expression will return a _set_ of text nodes, and (in XSLT 1.0) if you try and take the `value-of` a node set what you get is just the string value of the _first_ node in the set in document order, with the rest of the nodes in the set being ignored.  To get the values of _all_ of them you'd typically use `apply-templates` or `copy-of` instead of `value-of`, e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//text()[not(ancestor::node3)]"/>`